# property sheet - how can I remove the border?

Tags: dialog, border, propertysheet

I've embedded a property sheet in a dialog box IDC_CONTAINER by specifying the HWND of the container in the hwndParent of the property sheet header when creating the property sheet.  In the callback I specified the following...

```
int CALLBACK PSCallback (HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam)
{

    LONG Z, Y;

    switch (message)
    {
    case PSCB_PRECREATE:                    // Remove Title Bar and Borders.
                                            // SO FAR border removal not working

        ((LPDLGTEMPLATE)lParam)->style &= ~WS_CAPTION;

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The property sheet is displayed without a title bar as expected but with a border.  I expected the border to go away since WS_CAPTION contains the border style per the MSDN.

Is there some way to get rid of the border?

win32api no mfc c++

Comment: I may be confusing border and frame boundary.  Are they the same?  Anyway what I have looks like the border around a dialog.  I also cleared WS_DLGFRAME and WS_THICKFRAME but whatever the thing is, it's still there.

Comment: It turns out the property sheet has a DS_MODALFRAME, clearing that style gets rid of the border or whatever it is.

Comment: The actual value of style b4 I buggered with it is 90,080,0C4h. 80,000,000h is POPUP; 10,000,000h is maximize; 80,000 is system menu; 80h is MODALFRAME; 40 is set font; HAVE NO IDEA WHAT THE 4h is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I needed, see comments added to original posting.